# Filtering out CSS properties

Tags: linux, text-processing

I would like to split my CSS file into two separate files.

I want to know how I may write a script 
to find specific word and then to delete till the first semicolon (included).

For example:

```
body { background:#fff; border:solid 1px red;}
div { background:#fff; border:solid 1px red;}
```

Expected result should be without the background rule,
then continue on the same line and then go to the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is a job for regex:

```
sed -e 's/\Wbackground:[^;]\+;//g'
```

Change 'background:' for what you're asking.

The \W maches non-word character. [^;] matches anything that isn't ;, one or more times. Followed by ;, which is all then replaced by nothing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helps :) i just want to ask you one more question... where should i put the file name on this script?  ..